# Pulumi python resource naming convention

Tags: python, python-3.x, naming-conventions, pulumi

Is there a prebuilt way to include prefixes on resource names when you create them? I am looking for something similar to `terraform`, but I'm not sure if we need to create it programmatically...

In `terraform` I had something like:

```
variable "org" {
  type = string
  validation {
    condition     = length(var.org) <= 3
    error_message = "The org variable cannot be larger than 3 characters."
  }
}

variable "tenant" {
  type = string
  validation {
    condition     = length(var.tenant) <= 4
    error_message = "The tenant variable cannot be larger than 4 characters."
  }
}

variable "environment" {
  type = string
  validation {
    condition     = length(var.environment) <= 4
    error_message = "The environment variable cannot be larger than 4 characters."
  }
}
```

And I use the above variables to name an Azure resource group like:

```
module "resource_group_name" {
  source   = "gsoft-inc/naming/azurerm//modules/general/resource_group"
  name     = "main"
  prefixes = [var.org, var.tenant, var.environment]
}
```

It is possible to do something similar in `Pulumi`?  I saw a similar issue reported [here](https://github.com/pulumi/pulumi/issues/1518), but it looks like this is more under programmatic control(?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use Python's formatting functions directly, like

```
resource_group = = azure_native.resources.ResourceGroup("main",
    location="eastus",
    resource_group_name="{0}-{1}-{2}-{3}".format(org, tenant, environment, rgname))
```

You could also define a helper function and use it in multiple places.

Comment: That is true, having pulumi a programmatic center approach, also it seems that we can take in advance of the stack YAML configuration to get those values, and then we can use them in the way you've mentioned. They have this way to get the values from `Pulumi.<stack>.yaml` file on this way https://www.pulumi.com/docs/reference/pkg/python/pulumi/#configuration-and-metadata-1

Comment: Mikhail, can you check my answer please, I want to make sure if my assumptions about  [auto-naming resources](https://www.pulumi.com/docs/intro/concepts/resources/#autonaming) are well understood. I will appreciate your thoughts about it.

Answer (score 0):

Following the answer from [@Mikhail Shilkov](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1171619/mikhail-shilkov) I created a helper function to give format to the name of an storage account resource on azure. But before I used the configuration of my `dev` stack at `Pulumi.dev.yaml` to read the values I want to assign to the name of the storage account.
Taking as a reference the way of [setting and getting configuration values](https://www.pulumi.com/docs/intro/concepts/config/#setting-and-getting-configuration-values), I set it up the following values to be included in my `dev` stack:

```
pulumi config set org rhd
pulumi config set application wmlab
pulumi config set environment dev
```

As long those values are set, I can see them at the `Pulumi.dev.yaml` stack file: (* Pulumi give it the name of the project `wmlab-infrastructure` to those values)

```
config:
  azure-native:location: westeurope # This one was set it up when creating the pulumi python project
  wmlab-infrastructure:application: wmlab
  wmlab-infrastructure:environment: dev
  wmlab-infrastructure:org: rhd
```

Then from python I use [Config.require](https://www.pulumi.com/docs/reference/pkg/python/pulumi/#pulumi.Config.require) to get the value by giving the key in this way:

```
def generate_storage_account_name(name: str, number: int, org: str, app: str, env: str):
    return f"{name}{number}{org}{app}{env}"


config = pulumi.Config()
organization = config.require('org')
application = config.require('application')
environment = config.require('environment')
```

Then when creating the storage account name, I called the `generate_storage_account_name` helper function:

(* I am using `random.randint(a,b)` function to provide an integer value to the name of the storage account, it will make easier things when assigning it a name)

```
# Create an Azure Resource Group
resource_group = azure_native.resources.ResourceGroup(
    'resource_group',
    resource_group_name="{0}-{1}-{2}".format(organization, application, environment)
)

# Create an Azure resource (Storage Account)
account = storage.StorageAccount(
    'main',
    resource_group_name=resource_group.name,
    account_name=generate_storage_account_name('sa', random.randint(1,100000), organization, application, environment),
    sku=storage.SkuArgs(
        name=storage.SkuName.STANDARD_LRS,
    ),
    kind=storage.Kind.STORAGE_V2)
```

And it works. When creating the resources, the name of the storage account is using the helper function:

```
> pulumi up
Previewing update (rhdhv/dev)

View Live: https://app.pulumi.com/myorg/wmlab-infrastructure/dev/previews/549c2c34-853f-4fe0-b9f2-d5504525b073

     Type                                     Name                      Plan
 +   pulumi:pulumi:Stack                      wmlab-infrastructure-dev  create
 +   ├─ azure-native:resources:ResourceGroup  resource_group            create
 +   └─ azure-native:storage:StorageAccount   main                      create

Resources:
    + 3 to create

Do you want to perform this update? details
+ pulumi:pulumi:Stack: (create)
    [urn=urn:pulumi:dev::wmlab-infrastructure::pulumi:pulumi:Stack::wmlab-infrastructure-dev]
    + azure-native:resources:ResourceGroup: (create)
        [urn=urn:pulumi:dev::wmlab-infrastructure::azure-native:resources:ResourceGroup::resource_group]
        [provider=urn:pulumi:dev::wmlab-infrastructure::pulumi:providers:azure-native::default_1_29_0::04da6b54-80e4-46f7-96ec-b56ff0331ba9]
        location         : "westeurope"
        resourceGroupName: "rhd-wmlab-dev"
    + azure-native:storage:StorageAccount: (create)
        [urn=urn:pulumi:dev::wmlab-infrastructure::azure-native:storage:StorageAccount::main]
        [provider=urn:pulumi:dev::wmlab-infrastructure::pulumi:providers:azure-native::default_1_29_0::04da6b54-80e4-46f7-96ec-b56ff0331ba9]

        accountName      : "sa99180rhdwmlabdev" # HERE THE NAME GENERATED
       
        kind             : "StorageV2"
        location         : "westeurope"
        resourceGroupName: output<string>
        sku              : {
            name: "Standard_LRS"
        }
```

To read more about accessing config values from code [read here](https://www.pulumi.com/docs/intro/concepts/config/#code)

Pulumi has a way to autonaming resources, [it is explained here](https://www.pulumi.com/docs/intro/concepts/resources/#autonaming),but alter this scheme looks like is not possible or at least is not recommended, doing it can cause some issues and resources will be recreated.

> Overriding auto-naming makes your project susceptible to naming collisions. As a result, for resources that may need to be replaced, you should specify deleteBeforeReplace: true in the resource’s options. This option ensures that old resources are deleted before new ones are created, which will prevent those collisions.

If I understood well, I can override those auto-named resources which allow the `name` attribute on their API specification, but then when doing so is when naming collisions might be presented (?)

In my case I am using the [StorageAccount](https://www.pulumi.com/docs/reference/pkg/azure-native/storage/storageaccount/#account_name_python) resource on python azure API, and it does not allow override the property name so the helper function works well.

Comment: One problem with your approach is that you will get a new random number on every run, so Pulumi will think it's a new resource and will try to re-create it. Instead, you should generate a stable random number (or string) using `pulumi-random` provider. See [this example](https://github.com/pulumi/examples/blob/ca40203279f393c0c159dadcadc97c6007122997/google-native-ts-k8s-ruby-on-rails-postgresql/infra/config.ts#L24).

Comment: Do you know how can I use the `seed` parameter here at [`RandomInteger`](https://www.pulumi.com/docs/reference/pkg/random/randominteger/)?

Comment: What's the problem with it? Also, you don't need to use it, as the result will be stable across the resource lifecycle (until you delete it).

Comment: Then I am a bit confuse about use `pulumi-random` provider

Comment: On creation, it generates a random value and saves it to state. As long as the resource exists, the state value remains stable.